# Eclipse For wrong version of Java

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I want to make a mod for Minecraft, and i have Java and JDK 7, because it's not compatible with Java 8. but the new Eclipse is for Java 8, and i can't find anywhere a Eclipse version for Java 7.

Comment: So download an older version of eclipse.

Comment: You can still compile down to Java 7 using Java 8.  That feature hasn't been removed.

Comment: When you create a project in Eclipse, you are asked which JRE version you want to target. Pick jre7 when you don't want any Java 8 features.

Answer (score 4):

You can work with any JDK if your Eclipse supports the latest one. You need to install JDK7, then you go to `Window`, `Preferences`. Type **installed** in the field and choose `Installed JREs`. Then, give the path of your JDK. Finally, right click on your project, `Properties`, `Java compiler` and select the appropriate JDK and compiler compliance.